# R: Convert an incomplete matrix to two or three columns

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, reshape

If I have a table

```
ID   C1   C2   C3   C4   C5
 1                     
 2    HD   NS   VM          
 3                   DH   FV
 4    HD             DH
```

Now I have to convert it to the following table

```
ID  C
2   HD
2   NS
2   VM
3   DH
3   FV
4   HD
4   DH
```

What is the best way to make this conversion in R? This has to be done in R as part of a larger code?

Comment: Try `unlist` or such (in case it's a data frame)

Comment: What is the format/type of your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  gather(C, Value, -ID, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  select(-C) %>%
  arrange(ID)
dt2
  ID Value
1  2    HD
2  2    NS
3  2    VM
4  3    DH
5  3    FV
6  4    HD
7  4    DH
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "ID   C1   C2   C3   C4   C5
 1 NA NA NA NA NA                    
                 2    HD   NS   VM NA NA           
                 3    NA  NA  NA  DH FV
                 4    HD  NA NA   DH NA     ",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked very well. I should add that the format it was in was cvs so I had to upload the table in the method below `dt <- read.csv2("~/Desktop/R_class/Test.data.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings=c("","NA"))` adding the `na.strings=c("","NA")`

Answer (score 1):

Using `melt`

```
library(reshape)
na.omit(melt(dt,id.var='ID'))
   ID variable value
2   2       C1    HD
4   4       C1    HD
6   2       C2    NS
10  2       C3    VM
15  3       C4    DH
16  4       C4    DH
19  3       C5    FV
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg changed

Answer (score 1):

```
data <- as.data.frame(list(ID = c(1,2,3,4),
              C1 = c(NA,"HD",NA,"HD"),C2 = c(NA,"NS",NA,NA),C3 = c(NA,"VM",NA,NA),C4 = c(NA,NA,"DH","DH"), C5 = c(NA,NA,"FV",NA)))
```

You can use unlist, but to have the ID, you previously create a matrix of same size than your data, just with the IDS

```
plouf = matrix(data$ID,dim(data)[1],dim(data)[2]-1)
data$ID <- NULL
```

and then you use unlist and select the non NA data:

```
   result = as.data.frame(list(
  C = unlist(data)[!is.na(unlist(data,use.names = FALSE))], 
  ID = unlist(plouf)[!is.na(unlist(data))] ))
```

which leads :

```
 C ID
C12 HD  2
C14 HD  4
C22 NS  2
C32 VM  2
C43 DH  3
C44 DH  4
C53 FV  3
```